# Why do the const accessors of std::string return a reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, language-design, stdstring

The `std::string` accessors ([`back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back), [`front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front), [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at), and [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at)) have `const` and non-`const` overloads, as below:

```
char& x();
const char& x() const;
```

Why does the second version return a **`const` reference**, as opposed to simply returning the `char` **by value** (as a copy)?

According to the [rules of thumb on how to pass objects around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2139254/3425536), shouldn't small objects be passed by value when there's no need to modify the original?

Comment: One word: consistency (with `std::vector` for instance).

Comment: Why should it have different semantics than the non-const version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the caller might want a reference to the char, that reflects any changes made to it through non-const avenues.

```
std::string str = "hello";
char const& front_ref = static_cast<std::string const&>(str).front();
str[0] = 'x';
std::cout << front_ref; // prints x
```

Comment: changes to const object?

Comment: @ixSci: No. You can have a const reference to a non-const object. See my updated example.

Comment: Sure, but doesn't it look too much contrived? I can't imagine such a case whatsoever.

Comment: @ixSci: Just because you can't personally imagine a use case, doesn't mean the interface should be arbitrarily restricted.

Comment: Well, interface is done that way because of the consistency and because the `basic_string` template is not restricted to `char` only. It is obviously there not for some funny cases which no one will ever use.

Comment: @ixSci: No, it's that way because there's no reason to arbitrarily restrict it.

Comment: I agree with that - there is no need for the restriction. I just pointed out that the example is too much contrived to be seriously counted as the reason to include such an interface to the class.

Comment: @ixSci: Yeah. Probably. I was just demonstrating that you can have a const reference to a non-const object (your first comment seemed to indicate that you didn't know that). A more likely scenario would be returning a non-const member string from a function by const reference, and then the user might want a reference to one of its chars.

Comment: @ixSci: the example is there to illustrate the reason, and may not be the reason itself.

Answer (score 1):

Because context.

You're dealing with a container and functions with names that imply specific positional data.

```
std::string s = "hello world?";
const auto& s1 = s.back();
s.back() = '!';
```

Returning a reference here provides flexibility, it's also consistent with the non-const variants and other stl containers. After all these functions are actually members of `std::basic_string<char>`.

Remember that "rule of thumb" is a guideline not a rule.